# How to perform partial correlation analysis with a grouping variable on list of datasets

Tags: r, iteration, correlation, partial

I am using the following reproducible example that might suit my case. If possible, I have been trying to execute a partial correlation analysis between `mpg` and `disp,  hp, vs`. I am not sure if the `pcor function` can do that, but the code I have prepared is the following one:

```
 list = list(mtcars, mtcars)
    list = lapply(list, function(x) x %>%
                    mutate(gear = as.factor(gear)))
    library(ggm)
    lapply(list, function(x) x %>% 
             group_by(gear) %>% pcor(c(mpg, disp,  hp, vs), var(x)))
```

I am not sure about what it is wrong but I am getting as error:

```
Error in pcor(., c(mpg, disp, hp, vs), var(x)) : unused argument (var(x))
```

What would you suggest to sove this ? MoDo you recommend to use different and separated datasets to run this analysis but using a different iterative method (which the way I would like to use)?

Thanks

Comment: Your syntax doesn't really make any sense here. The `ggm::pcor` function takes two arguments, but you are passing three (remember when you use the pipe operator, the result of the last calculation is passed as the first argument of the following function). Also the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggm/ggm.pdf) say that the first argument should be a vector of integers, whereas you are passing a vector of unquoted column names outside of a quasiquotation context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax doesn't really make any sense here. The `ggm::pcor` function takes two arguments, but you are passing three (remember when you use the pipe operator, the result of the last calculation is passed as the first argument of the following function).

Also the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggm/ggm.pdf) say that the first argument, `u`, should be:

> a vector of integers of length > 1. The first two integers are the indices of variables the correlation of which must be computed. The rest of the vector is the
> conditioning set.

As it turns out, this is not quite right, since the example goes on to give a vector of *column names* to the argument `u`, which are used to subset the rows and columns of the matrix passed to argument `S`.

The bottom line is that, if you want a partial correlation for each level of `gear` for each data frame in your list, you will need to do something like:

```r
library(ggm)

lapply(list, function(x) {
  sapply(split(x, x$gear), function(x) {
    pcor(u = c('mpg', 'disp', 'hp', 'vs'), S = var(x))
  })
})
#> [[1]]
#>          3          4          5 
#> -0.3572209 -0.7089970 -0.2900153 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>          3          4          5 
#> -0.3572209 -0.7089970 -0.2900153
```

Comment: Thanks fro clarifying this.. But to be precise, which of the set employed as variable of control (do  'disp', 'hp', 'vs' control for mpg in this case, as I woud like to do)?

Comment: My understanding that this is the partial correlation of `mpg` and `disp`, conditioned on `hp` and `vs`

Comment: so is not possible at all to control one variable taking into the other three?

Comment: @12666727b9 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Partial correlation has to be between two variables. You can't have partial correlation of a single variable. In this case, we have the partial correlation between mpg and disp, conditioned on hp and vs. Can you explain what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually mine question was to control just mpg for the three subsequent variables. Moreover, as general question, I was wondering whether the variables for which variables are controlled for could be either numeric, dichotomic or both of them.

Comment: But you are using the `pcor` function. Do you not want partial correlation? There is no such thing as controlling an independent variable by other variables, unless you are modelling its relationship to a dependent variable. How you do this is dependent on the model you are using and what assumptions you are making. Perhaps writing a new question that shows the "big picture" of what you are actually trying to do would be helpful?

Comment: Probably I will do this. I would have just a theoretical question if you do not mind to answer. Should the controlling variables or all the variables enter in the partial correlation be dicothomic or not?

Comment: @12666727b9 I'm no statistician, but it should be OK to use both. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133203/partial-correlation-and-multiple-regression-controlling-for-categorical-variable)